# Why does cURL work when I ping an IP from my localhost, but not when I use it from 000webhostapp?

Tags: php, curl

I am using the following code to ping an IP address (courtesy of https://www.saotn.org/php-curl-check-website-availability/)

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP/cURL function to check a web site status. If HTTP status is not 200 or 302, or
 * the requests takes longer than 10 seconds, the website is unreachable.
 * 
 * Follow me on Twitter: @HertogJanR
 * Send your donation through https://www.paypal.me/jreilink. Thanks!
 *
 * @param string $url URL that must be checked
 */
function url_test( $url ) {
  $timeout = 10;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
  $http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_respond = trim( strip_tags( $http_respond ) );
  $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
  echo $http_code;
  if ( ( $http_code == "200" ) || ( $http_code == "302" ) ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    // return $http_code;, possible too
    return false;
  }
  curl_close( $ch );
}

$website = "192.168.X.X";
if( !url_test( $website ) ) {
  echo $website ." is down!";
}
else { echo $website ." functions correctly."; }
?>
```

Where 192.168.X.X is my default gateway.

When I run it via my localhost, it says 192.168.X.X functions correctly. However, when I run it on my website at 000webhostapp.com, It wait for 10 seconds and says 192.168.X.X is down! with a http code of 0. Any ideas on whats wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Because that IP is only local, and can be accessed from the local network only.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you know how I can check if my router is up and running any other way then?

Comment: You need to call a public IP address. Does your router have a public IP?

Comment: Tried it with my public IP as well, this time I got the reply "106.51.X.X doesnt work" both from my localhost and my website. Got it from www.whatismyip.com.

Comment: First of all, routers aren't often pingable by default. Secondly this sample code does a HTTP request. That's even more unlikely to be available from the outside.

Comment: PD of [PHP checking if server is alive](//stackoverflow.com/q/7792413) / [Pinging an IP address using PHP and echoing the result](//stackoverflow.com/q/8030789) / [Creating a ping uptime service with PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/7372780)

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending a ping, you're doing a cURL so checking if a webserver is up and running.

It works local because the management interface is reachable from your internal network.

To do an actual ping, other people have already done the work for you:

https://github.com/geerlingguy/Ping

```
$host = '106.x.x.x';
$ping = new Ping($host);
$latency = $ping->ping();
if ($latency !== false) {
    print 'Latency is ' . $latency . ' ms';
} else {
    print 'Host could not be reached.';
}
```